# mongoDB ignoring unique index

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongorepository

I built a REST service and I found out that a JSON String generated from an ObjectId by using Gson will be in a different format than that is produced by spring-boot. and if I send an ObjectId of an existing Document's _id field in GSON format to my REST service and save it to the collection by using mongorepository's save function, a new Document with duplicated _id will still be inserted even if a unique index is set on such field. But if I send ObjectId in a format that is produced by spring-boot everything works perfectly. I'm wondering what caused such a problem?

```
        "timestamp": 1558461711,
        "machineIdentifier": 5077764,
        "processIdentifier": 21816,
        "counter": 13546695,
        "date": "2019-05-21T18:01:51.000+0000",
        "time": 1558461711000,
        "timeSecond": 1558461711(generated by spring-boot)


        "counter": 13546695,
        "randomValue1": 9256029,
        "randomValue2": 856,
        "timestamp": 1558461711(by GSON)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with mongodb it is better to use org.bson.Document (which is provided by mongodb dependency) or some other mongodb class to convert document to json rather then GSON.

```
Document document = new Document();
document.put("_id", new ObjectId());
String json = document.toJson()
```

`document.toJson()` should stringify ObjectId in a right way.
Actually the output of the code above will be:

```
{ "_id" : { "$oid" : "5ce51fb47dda11a8507087eb" } }
```

Which is a valid format for mongodb, not sure about how SpringBoot will react on it.
Anyway, hope it'll help.

Comment: Hmm...not sure why but it seems that SpringBoot cant get the correct ObjectId from that stringified value.